# Unable to create a configuration directory for [FishShell] Please set the $XDG_CONFIG_HOME variable

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal, osx, fish

I'm getting this error when starting fishshell:

```
melanie:~ melanie$ fish

fish: Unable to create a configuration directory for fish. Your personal
settings will not be saved. Please set the $XDG_CONFIG_HOME variable to
a directory where the current user has write access.
```

How do I set that variable?

Comment: What do `echo $HOME` and `echo $XDG_CONFIG_HOME` output? How about `mkdir -p ~/.config/fish/`?

Comment: ridiculous_fish, thank you so much for responding! (Michael Mrozek thank you for editing!)

I followed your instructions in both, bash, and fish... each time was the same. echo $HOME returned /Users/melanie and echo $XDG_CONFIG_HOME returned nothing... it just spaced one line and then showed the terminal prompt melanie:~ melanie$

---

do you think: mkdir -p ~/.config/fish/ and then XDG_CONFIG_HOME = ~/.config/fish/ ???

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to set XDG_CONFIG_HOME (the error message is misleading). On OS X, what should happen is that fish creates the directory `~/.config/fish/`. If that fails, it may mean that you don't have write permissions for the directory. So try creating it yourself via `mkdir -p ~/.config/fish/`. Does it work? If not, what error do you get?

Comment: Okay, I did what you said, thanks for sticking with me, here's what I've got: 

`melanie:~ melanie$ mkdir -p ~/.config/fish/` 
`mkdir: /Users/melanie/.config/fish/: Permission denied`

I just don't understand why I'm receiving a `Permission denied`? would `sudo` work?

Comment: Check permissions in your home directory and `.config` therein (if present): `ls -ald ~` or `stat ~` (substitute `~/.config` for the latter) and append the output to the question please.

Comment: Thanks for the reply peterph! here's what I got: `melanie:~ melanie$ ls -ald ~`#Output:
`drwxr-xr-x+ 31 melanie  staff  1054 Dec 31 18:15 /Users/melanie`"""after that I tried""" `melanie:~ melanie$ stat ~/.config` #Output: `16777218 1147249 drwxr-xr-x 4 root staff 0 136 "Dec 30 19:21:11 2014" "Jan 19 02:07:39 2014" "Jan 19 02:07:39 2014" "Jan 19 02:07:39 2014" 4096 0 0 /Users/melanie/.config` #it looks like the output is saying "Staff" my guess is that needs to say admin, yes? Thanks again!